# Position footer at the bottom of the page at all times

Tags: html, css

I have currently got a footer in my website that I want to have at the bottom of the page at all times. It is only one line on most screens so I thought it would be a good idea to have it always there. I want to stay away from JavaScript too.

CSS

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <p class="footer">Design by <a class="footer" href="http://www.tropilac.com">Tropilac</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It currently works but since I am using the margin CSS tag it pushes it to the left of the screen too far.div.footer {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: Got it, 

Change the width to 80% to fix the problem!

    width:80%;

HTML stays the same

New CSS

 div.footer {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width:80%;
 }

Comment: Please, instead of commenting your own question, edit it. Did you find solution yet?

Comment: This question has been asked like thousand times. There's even a tag for this type of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sticky-footer .

Comment: But this just works if you have it in another absolute div with 100% height i guess? I do this with position: fixed; bottom: 0px;

Comment: This works - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: fixed` if you need to show at all times.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="footer">Design by <a href="http://www.tropilac.com">Tropilac</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And also add a spacer div with height of the footer to see all of possibly hidden content.

Comment: @fassl its not a good practice to add unnecessary html like spacer divs.

Comment: @kilmazing it is necessary to overcome the issue that content probably will be hidden by the footer, if you do it with a spacer div or margin on last child of body or whatever of thousands of possibilities there may are is subject to one self. I rather have a footer spacer div on bottom of page than manipulating margins of block elements which actually dont have anything to do with the footer itself. What is the good practice of overcoming this issue?

Comment: @fassl I think if we're worried about the footer hiding content than position:fixed isn't the answer. I think we'd want to go back to position: absolute and dynamically adjust the positioning of the footer based on the offset of the last element. This would require JS of course.

Comment: @kilmazing relying on something the user can disable is also not good practice imo.  But do we even need to do it with js? If you have a fullpage wrapper containing all content with margin-bottom the height of the footer which is positioned absolute, aren't we fine then?

Comment: @fassl agreed relying on js for layout isn't a good practice. Since an absolutely positioned element is out of the document flow your margin suggestion doesn't work. Here is a fiddle with your suggested markup: http://jsfiddle.net/n21dw0z8/

Comment: @kilmazing although this is my preferred way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/n21dw0z8/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try positioning your element to fixed. This is useful for elements such as a footer as if you do something like this:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

This will give you a footer that stays at the bottom of the viewport. One drawback is that if the content is longer than the page the footer will still show positioned at the bottom of the page. This code will also give you your 80% width.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p16rwgnn/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` and `bottom:0` to get what you want

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
```